# ill effects of not fulfilling a vow- Tirupati

Tags: gods, punishment

From ancient times, pepole visiting tirupati take a vow of tonsuring their hair if their wish gets fulfilled. What happens if a person doesn't fulfill this vow? He took a vow of tonsuring his hair if his wish gets granted.His wish gets granted but he dont want to tonsure his hair now.Will God punish him for this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100446/discussion-on-question-by-jacky-ill-effects-of-not-fulfilling-a-vow-tirupati).

Comment: No doubt sir...just because you said that you fulfilled some vows in advance..so I thought if you can give another example of any vow which you fulfilled in advance, apart from the discussed one. If you don't mind.

Comment: @lazy lubber..you there sir?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [God's punishment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36493/gods-punishment)

Comment: @sarvabhouma i am not able to get to the question u linked, is that deleted?

Comment: @PrakashK Yeah it is deleted now. It's the same question asked by the same OP.

Answer (score 1):

Lord Balaji never punishes anyone. If you look into the history of Tirumala you will be admired how the process of vow fulfillment came into effect at Tirumala
.
https://www.tirumala.org/TempleLegend.aspx

Comment: This is a link-only answer. You need to quote the relevant part from the website you linked. See how to reference content from other websites by using block quotes [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes).